# Python sys.argv TypeErrors with printing function results?

Tags: python, command-line, arguments

I have been trying to learn how to use sys.argv properly, while calling an executable file from the command line.

I wanted to have the functions results print to the command line when passing the filename and argument on the command line but, I get a TypeError.

So far I have:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import mechanize
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import sys

def dictionary(word):
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    response = br.open('http://www.dictionary.reference.com')
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.form['q'] = sys.argv
    br.submit()
    definition = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read())
    trans = definition.findAll('td',{'class':'td3n2'})
    fin = [i.text for i in trans]
    query = {}
    for i in fin:
        query[fin.index(i)] = i
    return query

print dictionary(sys.argv)
```

When I call this:

```
./this_file.py 'pass'
```

I am left with this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./hot.py", line 20, in <module>
    print dictionary(sys.argv)    
  File "./hot.py", line 10, in dictionary
    br.form['q'] = sys.argv
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_form.py", line 2782, in __setitem__
    control.value = value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_form.py", line 1217, in __setattr__
    raise TypeError("must assign a string")
TypeError: must assign a string
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

`br.form['q'] = sys.argv`

you are assigning a *list of strings* here *instead* of a string.

```
>>> type(sys.argv)
<type 'list'>
>>> type(sys.argv[0])
<type 'str'>
>>>
```

You want to identify a specific string to assign via an index.

Most likely it will be be index 1 given what you have in your post (and since index 0 is the name of the script). So perhaps

`br.form['q'] = sys.argv[1]`

will do for you. Of course it could be another index too, depending on your particular application/needs.

Note as @Dougal observes in a helpful comment below, the function parameter `word` in the function is not being used. You are calling your `dictionary` function sending it `sys.argv` and then ought to refer to `word` inside the function. The type doesn't change only the name that you refer to the command line args inside your function. The idea of `word` is good as it avoids the use of global variables. If you refer to use globals (not really encouraged) then removing `word` is recommended as it will be confusing to have it there).

So your statement should really read

`br.form['q'] = word[1]`

Comment: Levon thanks for being patient and answering my questions.  I should have stressed the fact that I haven't used sys.argv much.  I was thinking that kwargs used lists and tuples not argv.

Comment: @tijko No problem. *No one* here was born knowing Python (or anything else :) From your previous question and error message I suspected this line to be the problem. I hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: Right on, and much appreciated.  It fixed the problem and I understand why! :D

Comment: @tijko Note also that you're passing an argument `word` to the `dictionary` function, but then you just go ahead and use `sys.argv` directly. You probably want to use `word` inside the function and call it like `dictionary(sys.argv[1])`.

Comment: @Dougal That is an excellent point. If you are ok with this, I will paraphrase your comment in my answer.

Comment: @Dougal I've gone ahead done this.  Is your reasoning to make the code clear, or something else?  To me, it seems to be straight forward less confusing way of writing it.

Comment: @tijko Using it directly is fine, but then you should take out the unused `word` parameter to your function, which is confusing. The advantage of using `word` is that then you could call the `dictionary` function from other code, maybe in a loop over multiple words from the command-line or as part of some other task or wherever else you might want to use it.